# Don't run JS in Web Browser c#

Tags: c#, forms, browser

I try to show a web site in Form using web browser, but when I run my project the web browser don't run JS files, this files are from web site.

this is my code in Form class:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    web_content.Navigate(urlString: "www.mywebsite.com");
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set property of browser component.

```
web_content.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```